# How to see photos shared in a folder in a sequence

Tags: directory

Someone shared a folder with dozens of photos with me. I am in Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox 16.02.
The only way I found out to see the photos in a sequence is to
 - download one by one (did not manage to download all at the same time) and
 - then use the Image Viewer (program) with the Previous/Next option.

Question: is there a simplier way to do this?

Greetings
ewst

Answer (score 0):

In Image Viewer, select View > Slideshow. Edit > Preferences > Slideshow to configure how long each image appears; 5 seconds by default.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the problem, you want to download all the files at one go, right? If this is correct, there is an add-on for Firefox called "[Downloadthemall](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/downthemall/)". It might help.